# Voting smart contract help highest voted function?

Tags: solidity, voting

first, I apologize for this very simple question. I'm starting my studies on smart contract
can someone explain highest voted function in this contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Voting{

    string[] public members;
    mapping(string => uint) public memberVote;
    mapping(address => bool) public voted;

    function addMember(string memory name) public {
        bool repeated=false;
        for(uint i=0; i < members.length; i++){
            if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked((name))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(members[i]))){
                repeated = true;
            }
        }
        if(repeated==false){
            members.push(name);
            memberVote[name] = 0;
        }
    }

    function Vote(string memory name) public{
        require(voted[msg.sender]==false, 'one address one vote');
        memberVote[name] = memberVote[name]+1;
        voted[msg.sender]=true;
    }

    function highestVoted() public view returns(string memory){
        uint maxIndex=0;
        uint maxVote=0;
        for(uint i = 0; i<members.length; i++){
            if(memberVote[members[i]]>maxVote){
                maxIndex=i;
                maxVote=memberVote[members[i]];
            }
        }
        return members[maxIndex];
    }

    function getMembers() public view returns(string[] memory){
        return members;
    }
    function getVotes(string memory member) public view returns(uint){
        return memberVote[member];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to apologize :) we all start somewhere!

The `highestVoted` function in this contract is used to find the member with the **highest number of votes**. Here's a breakdown of how it works:

Initialize two variables, `maxIndex` and `maxVote`, to store the highest-voted member's index and vote count.

```
   uint maxIndex=0; // Index of the highest-voted member
   uint maxVote=0; // Count of votes
```

Loop through the members array with a for loop.

```
for(uint i = 0; i<members.length; i++)
```

For each member, check if their vote count is greater than the current maxVote.

```
if(memberVote[members[i]]>maxVote)
```

If a member's vote count is higher, update maxIndex to their index and maxVote to their vote count.

```
maxIndex=i; // Update the maxIndex
maxVote=memberVote[members[i]]; // Update maxVote (higher than the previous)
```

After the loop completes, return the member with the highest vote count using members[maxIndex].

```
  return members[maxIndex];
```

This function determines the current leader in the voting process.

Answer (score 0):

Highest Voted Function
Contract function that counts and performs a specific action when a certain number of votes is achieved in the system.

addMember(string memory name) public
Vote(string memory name) public

function addMember(string memory name) public {
// function body here
}

function Vote(string memory name) public {
// function body here
}

highestVoted() public view returns(string memory)
function highestVoted() public view returns (string memory) {
uint maxIndex = 0;
uint maxVotes = 0;

```
for (uint i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    if (memberVote[members[i]] > maxVotes) {
        maxVotes = memberVote[members[i]];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}

return members[maxIndex];
```

getMembers() public view returns(string[] memory)
function getMembers() public view returns (string[] memory) {
string[] memory activeMembers = new string;
uint activeIndex = 0;
for (uint i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
if (memberVote[members[i]] > 0) {
activeMembers[activeIndex] = members[i];
activeIndex++;
}
}
return activeMembers;
}

getVotes(string memory member) public view returns(uint)
function getVotes(string memory member) public view returns (uint) {
require(memberVote[member] > 0, "Member does not exist or has no votes.");
return memberVote[member];
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).